# Bootstrap row shifting vertically on screen resize

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

When I look at my portfolio site (https://grimzero.github.io/Portfolio/) I have a projects window that I am trying to make responsive. The issue however is that whenever I resize the screen, the row they are in is shifted down to the middle of the screen and I have no idea why this would happen.

There is some weird things going on in this html, but I dont understand what. Can someone point me in the direction of what might be happening here?

```html
<div class="row">
    <app-about class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-lg-4"></app-about>
    <div class="col-6 row p-0">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
<!--the projects angular component is put here with the router-->
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the projects component

```html
<div class="container" style="margin-left: 15px;">
    <div class="row">
        <app-project *ngFor="let project of filtered | async" 
        [project]="project" class="p-0"></app-project>
    </div>
</div>
```

which  shows a collection of this object

```html
<div [routerLink]="project.route" routerLinkActive="active" class="p-0"
    style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); width: 150px;">
    <img [src]="project.preview"
        [ngStyle]="{'max-width.px': project.thumbnailSize, 'max-height.px': project.thumbnailSize}">
</div>
```

[image][image]

Update:
[image]

Comment: Could you show HTML code  of your page where image is displayed

Comment: I have added my code. I should not have assumed people will look at my actual webpage and look for it. This should be pretty much clear on what the issue is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to give `height: 100%` to `app-project` container, to ensure it takes all time the full height of the his parent.

Comment: This does not seem to change anything sadly. The result is the same

Comment: Did you add this to <app-projects> element?

Comment: I had to add it in the div above it, since the router-outlet component is taking care of generating that component. Code just didnt recompile because of my autosave in VSCode. I combined your answer with @Beller and that seems to have done the trick. although the layout has been shifted slightly to the left even though its using columns for everything... (Going to edit another screenshot in for that)

Comment: I also think this causes an issue with the flexbox they are in, but I am not sure if this is related. the box seems to be a little too big for the screen

Answer (score 2):

```
<app-about _ngcontent-tdo-c2="" class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-lg-4" _nghost-tdo-c3="">
<div _ngcontent-tdo-c2="" class="col-6 row p-0">
```

Here you should use something similar like in :

```
<div _ngcontent-tdo-c2="" class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-lg-8 row p-0">
```

Another hand after the mentioned div there is an app-project tag which should contain the container class. (after that remove container class from div)

```
<app-projects _nghost-tdo-c5="" class="container">
```

[image]

Comment: The first part of your reply makes so much sense as to why its going wrong there. I changed it to ```class: "col"``` instead since I am pretty sure that should work. If I dont specify it should fill the width. as for the app projects container, its generated from the router outlet so I dont know if its possible to add a container to it there.